# pynput - Importing keyboard and mouse

Tags: python, pynput

I am having some trouble importing some things from pynput library.

In my code I want use the a python library (pynput) to do some actions in the mouse and in keyboard. When I import just the keyboard or the mouse it works but when importing both at some time it give me some errors.

Here is my code:

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

from time import sleep

mouse = Controller()
keyboard = Controller()
rock1x = 691
rock1y = 466
rock2x = 548
rock2y = 350
rock3x = 687
rock3y = 234

while (1):
    drop1x = 1183
    drop1y = 325
    drop2x = 1220
    drop2y = 325
    drop3x = 1263
    drop3y = 325
    drop4x = 1303
    drop4y = 325

    for i in range(8):
        sleep(2.5)
        mouse.position = (rock2x,rock2y)
        sleep(0.3)
        mouse.press(Button.left)
        mouse.release(Button.left)
        sleep(2.1)

        mouse.position = (rock3x,rock3y)
        sleep(0.3)

        mouse.press(Button.left)
        mouse.release(Button.left)
        sleep(2.1)

        mouse.position = (rock1x,rock1y)

        sleep(0.2)
        mouse.press(Button.left)
        mouse.release(Button.left)

    for i in range(3):
        keyboard.press(Key.shift)
        for x in range(6):
            mouse.position = (drop1x,drop1y)
            sleep(0.3)
            mouse.press(Button.left)
            mouse.release(Button.left) 
            drop1y=drop1y+35
        for x in range(6):
            mouse.position = (drop2x,drop2y)
            sleep(0.3)
            mouse.press(Button.left)
            mouse.release(Button.left) 
            drop2y=drop2y+35
        for x in range(6):
            mouse.position = (drop3x,drop3y)
            sleep(0.3)
            mouse.press(Button.left)
            mouse.release(Button.left) 
            drop3y=drop3y+35
        for x in range(6):
            mouse.position = (drop4x,drop4y)
            sleep(0.3)
            mouse.press(Button.left)
            mouse.release(Button.left) 
            drop4y=drop4y+35
        keyboard.release(Key.shift)
    sleep(3)
```

When I run this code the follow error show up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mining.py", line 29, in <module>
    mouse.press(Button.left)
  File "/home/filipe/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pynput/keyboard/_base.py", line 366, in press
    if resolved.is_dead:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_dead'
```

But when I comment the second line:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
```

the code runs until:

```
keyboard.press(Key.shift)
```

and gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mining.py", line 48, in <module>
    keyboard.press(Key.shift)
NameError: name 'Key' is not defined
```

How should I import from pynput library to use the mouse and keyboard?

Comment: What is the error? What have you tried already? See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I already edited my question with some new info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you are importing two different `Controller`s.

The second one (`pynput.keyboard.Controller`) overrides the first one since it is the last one defined. Therefore, your variable `mouse` is actually a `pynput.keyboard.Controller` object and not a `pynput.mouse.Controller` object like you expected.

The error happens when you call `mouse.press(Button.left)` because the `Keyboard` object is trying to press a `Button`, which it cannot do (it can only press `Key`s).

To fix this, import the modules "generally" using `import/as` instead of importing "specific" parts of them using `from/import`:

```
import pynput.mouse    as ms
import pynput.keyboard as kb
```

This way, you can differentiate between the two controllers:

```
mouse    = ms.Controller()
keyboard = kb.Controller()
```

Hope this helps – please respond with any feedback!

Comment: Also be sure to change every time you use `Button` to `ms.Button` and `Key` to `kb.Key`. For example, `Button.left` has to be changed to `ms.Button.left`.

Comment: Thanks!! Your solution works. I wrote my code as similar of yours. Now I have 'mouse = pynput.mouse.Controller()' and 'keyboard = pynput.keyboard.Controller()'. I import the library this way: 'from pynput.mouse import Button', 'from pynput.keyboard import Key' and 'import pynput'

Comment: Happy to help! Also, (I don't mean to be rude or pushy, but) please consider [accepting my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Comment: Opps sorry, kind new in the stackoverflow community. Sometimes I forget to do those things, I already accepted your answer.